# Sending a raw file with a SMS message - [Code Provided]

Tags: android, sms, attachment, android-intent

I have this code to send an SMS message with an attachment that is coming from the `raw/` folder:

```
String uri= "mmsto:";
String uri2 = "android.resource://[my_package]/";
Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
mmsIntent.setType("Audio/basic");
mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri2+R.raw.sound));
mmsIntent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);  
startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

This code is esecuted when I press a button `button1`. However, It opens an SMS application but with NO attachment.

Am I doing this wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the attachment as asset will do the work.

```
context.getAssets().open(attachmentFile);
```

P.S: To be clear, move the file to asset folder :)

Something like here:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(attachmentFile);
//write the input stream data somewhere then parse the uri as you do.
mmsIntent.setType("Audio/basic");
mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri2+R.raw.sound));
mmsIntent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);  
startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

Comment: I'm afraid of moving my sounds from raw/ to assest/. Can I play my sounds if they are in the assest folder ?

Comment: Yes you can. For example on the SDcard, you can query the content provider to show you all the media (lets say music) of some type.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski hey how can I add image to uri ? this is code 
        String uriText = "mmsto:123456789?body=" + Uri.encode("some subject text here33")+ "&image=" + imageUri;
but it does not attach image to mms.